# Assignment in class changes type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to encapsulate some data into a `class`, but something strange happens:

```
>>> class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value):
        print(value)
        print(type(value))

        self.value = value,

        print(self.value)
        print(type(self.value))

>>> f = Foo(5)
5
<class 'int'>
(5,)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Why changes the type from `int` to `tuple` (in Python 3.3.0, Windows, IDLE)?

Comment: What did you *think* the comma in `a = a,` would do? Nothing?

Comment: I _thought_ there was no comma... Usually typos in Python do not hide themselves like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing it to a tuple here:

```
self.value = value,
```

The comma at the end of the line means you're creating a tuple with `value` as the first value. For example:

```
>>> 3
3
>>> 3,
(3,)
```

After that `self.value` is a `tuple` and no longer an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the comma in this line:

```
self.value = value,
```

the above code is actually equivalent to this:

```
self.value = (value,)
```

As you can see, it reassigns `self.value` to a tuple that has `value` as the first item.

---

You should remember that it is the *comma* that creates a tuple, not the parenthesis (if any).

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> x = 1, 2, 3
>>> x
(1, 2, 3)
>>> x = (1, 2, 3)
>>> x
(1, 2, 3)
>>>
```